# Como evitar que Item iniciado numa pagina continue em outra em Latex?

Tags: latex

Eu trabalho com um template da COPPE/UFRJ Coppetex no meu trabalho de dissertação.

Fiz uma lista numerada com o comando `\item` mas como a lista ficou no final da pagina tem um dos pontos que iniciou o final da pagina e terminou no inicio da pagina seguente.

O problema que ficou tão pouco nessa ultima linha na nova pagina que fica feio.

Dai queria saber se alguém conhece algum comando que coloque aquele item todo na seguente pagina, ou melhor ainda se alguém que conheca algum packages que resolva esse problema.

PS.> tem quem me disse para usar `\pagebreak` o que resolve, mas penso que não é o caso usar incluir um comando cada vez que esse problema aparecer.

```
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item As âncoras são progressivamente movidas avante à medida que o lançamento é feito. Um barco de movimentação de âncora move sucessivamente cada âncora da proa enquanto outro barco movimenta as âncoras de popa, Figura 3.5;
%\pagebreak
\item Um barco de alimentação ou uma balsa auxiliar fornece os tubos (em geral, 12m);
\item O tubo é corretamente posicionado e avança sucessivamente para as estações de soldagem com um ou mais passos de solda sendo executados em cada uma delas;

\end{enumerate}
```

[image: Visualização do Erro]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar um `minipage` para forçar que o conteúdo de um item esteja sempre na mesma página. Não é muito melhor do que a sua solução atual, no sentido de que você precisa usar esse comando juntamente com cada `\item` onde deseja evitar a divisão, mas é melhor do que o `pagebreak` porque você não força a quebra de página e deixa isso a cargo do LaTeX.

A solução que eu usei certa vez foi criar um comando novo pra usar com junto com o comando `item`, facilitando a criação do `minipage`:

```
\newcommand{\samepageblock}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}}
```

Dai, ao criar um item, basta incluir o texto no novo comando:

```
\item \samepageblock{Aqui vai o texto que não pode ser separado em páginas diferentes}
```

Nesse exemplo [disponível online no Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/2875968hmrpbp#/7778366/), sem o uso desse comando o resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E com o uso do comando apenas no último item (para efeito ilustrativo) o resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deve ser possível alterar o comando `item` diretamente (usando [`renewcommand`](https://aprendolatex.wordpress.com/tag/renewcommand/)) para sempre incluir um `minipage` no texto e assim não precisar usar esse novo comando manualmente a cada novo item criado. Mas eu não sei se isso é uma boa ideia, pois toda a documentação que eu já li a respeito diz para evitar a todo custo alterar o comportamento do comando `item` diretamente.

Código completo do exemplo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% ---------------------------------
\newcommand{\samepageblock}[1]{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}}
% ---------------------------------

\begin{itemize}

\item Morbi vitae sapien odio. Ut ipsum lectus, viverra nec vehicula nec, consectetur in turpis.

\item Curabitur sagittis ipsum nec purus imperdiet, a vestibulum nunc ultrices.

\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sagittis ut velit nec auctor. Fusce convallis arcu id sem rhoncus tristique. Sed blandit, dui ac eleifend ultricies, neque arcu luctus ligula, suscipit euismod ligula metus nec diam. Vestibulum non tristique est. Duis venenatis rhoncus felis, non ultrices nulla malesuada et. Duis quis dolor laoreet nisi accumsan tempor. Donec ac nibh vitae mi tempus laoreet.

\item Proin a semper nisi. Vivamus ut erat sapien. Praesent quis nisl ut nisl ultricies dictum sed eu est. Etiam varius tincidunt ante id aliquam. Nullam felis lorem, pulvinar suscipit turpis eu, ultrices porta justo. Quisque non nunc vitae elit blandit viverra. Suspendisse malesuada finibus odio ut aliquet. Pellentesque finibus purus erat, non suscipit velit malesuada id. Nunc finibus magna metus, non vulputate diam rhoncus dictum. Nullam pellentesque lorem erat, dictum sagittis dui cursus congue. Integer eget lacus at arcu fringilla porta in at augue.

\item Aliquam pulvinar metus ante, id porttitor velit hendrerit eu. Sed vitae mattis purus. Integer efficitur turpis elit, id volutpat libero sollicitudin ac. Nunc a justo quis nulla porta tempus. Aliquam sit amet purus eros. Curabitur mattis urna eget justo hendrerit porttitor. Phasellus iaculis metus vel lacus lacinia, vel tempor mi ullamcorper. Donec interdum sapien eu auctor faucibus. Donec luctus mattis faucibus. Sed velit neque, sollicitudin eget urna vel, feugiat fringilla mi. Duis vehicula elit quis sapien egestas, a varius eros facilisis.

\item Proin finibus, risus a sollicitudin faucibus, libero nulla tempor felis, eu posuere est augue at ante. Vivamus pulvinar laoreet purus vel consequat. Phasellus eget pharetra lorem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec augue orci, suscipit eget tortor quis, feugiat tristique risus. Maecenas augue odio, varius sed risus molestie, interdum lacinia elit. Aenean magna ex, consectetur a volutpat quis, feugiat at enim. Proin eget accumsan augue. Nulla vitae ornare nibh. Suspendisse aliquam, velit posuere eleifend auctor, ex metus sollicitudin ligula, vitae ultrices orci nulla ut mauris. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut fringilla fermentum mauris et ultricies. Phasellus semper dictum turpis, laoreet consequat massa pulvinar ut. Suspendisse est augue, tempus non enim at, rhoncus pellentesque eros. Sed et aliquam leo.

\item \samepageblock{Duis sed elit ut elit pellentesque aliquam non at risus. Fusce libero tellus, tincidunt quis tellus id, faucibus aliquet mauris. Ut in ornare turpis. Nullam a lobortis odio. Nunc non elit vitae ligula imperdiet euismod. Fusce blandit et diam sed blandit. Maecenas lobortis egestas magna vitae hendrerit. Donec efficitur libero ut leo dictum, non accumsan elit luctus. Integer ut tincidunt leo. Nullam ut nulla enim. Maecenas sodales, arcu non ornare posuere, tellus elit mollis arcu, non tincidunt mi turpis vel urna. Pellentesque porttitor nunc et lectus efficitur pretium. Nam fermentum id purus luctus tempor.}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, é uma solução melhor que forçar um `\pagebreak`, eu vou esperar mais um pouco para aceitar a resposta, para ele ficar aberta ainda pois talvez outro guru do latex conheça outro método também útil. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente o Latex consegue acertar isto sozinho...
Neste caso experimenta:

```
\item
\begin{samepage}
Um barco de alimentação ou uma balsa auxiliar fornece os tubos (em geral, 12m);
\end{samepage}
\item ...
```

um abraço
JJ